# XGBoost Architecture Diagram required

Tags: machine-learning-model, xgboost, loss-function, regularization, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

Good Day!

My topic is general and theory related, about XGBoost working. I am searching XGBoost Architecture Diagram. I know it works on principles of Decision Trees, Bagging, Random Forest, Boosting, Gradient Boosting but to sum up all I need a visual representation of these for XGBoost. There I may be able to show weights assigned. Hope I am able to deliver my query. Can any body highlight any resource or share the material? I tried searching on Internet but in vain. I couldn’t find XGBoost Architecture Diagram as per theory. Please share. Many Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of architecture diagram you have in mind. XGBoost ist not a neural network with connected layers.

Comment: I have found. I mean the inputs and outputs of different stages of working of algorithm.

Comment: parameters as inputs and outputs.